# Optimize an R code having for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization, data-processing

here is my code, basically I am trying to convert data to wide format which may or may not have duplicate data. I tried to use for-each and parallel but still it takes more time, Can anyone suggest any change

This is the data I am processing:-

```
Param1: 1, , 753360af0c8949c0aeab64d520599656
Param2: Value2
Param3: value3
Param4: Value4
Param1: 2, , 8c8c659813d842c5bab2ddba9483ea5a
Param2: Value5
Param4: value6
Param3: Value7
```

So basically I need a wide format but the the above example contains 4 parameters. The file can have 10 varying number of parameters as the text file comes from different sources.

The result should look like this:-

```
Param1                                    Param2  Param3  param4    
1 753360af0c8949c0aeab64d520599656        Value2  Value3  Value4    
2 8c8c659813d842c5bab2ddba9483ea5a        Value5  Value6  Value7
```

here is the code for the same:-

```
f <-  read.table("./Sample.txt",header = FALSE, sep = ":",fill=TRUE, row.names=NULL)

f[,2] <- paste(f[,2],f[,3],f[,4])

c <- unique(f[,1])

rw <- round(nrow(f) / length(c)) + 1

result <- data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=length(c),nrow=rw))

colnames(result) <- t(c)

wh <- which(f[,1]==c[1])

for(i in 1:(length(wh)-1)) {

  print(i)

  tmp <- f[(wh[i]:(wh[i+1]-1)),]

  result[i,] <- t(tmp[,2][match(colnames(result),tmp[,1])])



}
```

I have more than 10,00,000 row to process and the above code does not complete even after a day.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll receive more help if you provide a reproducible example

Comment: Pijush ; to be explicit, if you can add a small example of your data and the expected result to your question please. This will make it a lot easier to comment on your code  but also offer alternate approaches - of which there are many optimised ways to reshape data

Comment: I have added the data for your reference

Comment: Thanks for adding - can you clarify: is it a two column dataframe or ... ??. For the example that you have added, could you also indicate what you want the result to look like please

Comment: Added, I hope it is clear now. Sorry for not being clear the first time

Comment: Could you maybe upload (give a link) a subset of the data you want to transform?

Comment: I have given the example for the data but cannot share the exact data as I don't have rights on the data.